# Overridden onMessage of MessageListner not getting called in Spring Kafka Consumer Unit Test

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-kafka

I am writing Kafka Consumer Unit Test, and need to Mock the Service of my KafkaConsumer for testing the Kafka Consumer independently. But, the mockObject of Service is not getting invoked, instead Spring is creating the original Service class object and calling it. Thus, my mock class object not getting called.

KafkaConsumer :

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor (onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class KafkaEventConsumer {

  private final MyService requestService;

  @KafkaListener (topics = "${kafka.topic:topic-name}")
  public void receive(@Payload String message) throws Exception {
    try {
      LOGGER.debug("Received message:{} ", message);
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      ForecastRequest forecastRequest = mapper.readValue(message, ForecastRequest.class);

      JobDetail jobDetail = requestForecastService.refreshForecasts(forecastRequest);
      if (jobDetail.getJobStatus() != JobStatus.complete) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to Refresh Forecast for ProgramId-{}, JobId-{}, JobStatus-{}",
            forecastRequest.getProgramId(), jobDetail.getJobId(), jobDetail.getJobStatus());
        throw new Exception("Internal Server Error");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Failed to Refresh Forecast for Forecast Request {}", message, e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Kafka Consumer Test :

```
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles ("kafkatest")
@SpringBootTest (classes = ForecastEventConsumerApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class KafkaEventConsumerTest {

  private static String TOPIC = "topic-name";

  @Mock
  private MyServiceImpl myServiceMock;

  @InjectMocks
  private KafkaEventConsumer kafkaEventConsumer;

  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

  @ClassRule
  public static final KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true,3, TOPIC);


  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    kafkaEventConsumer = new KafkaEventConsumer(myServiceMock);


    // set up the Kafka producer properties
    Map<String, Object> senderProperties = KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());

    // create a Kafka producer factory
    ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(senderProperties);

    // create a Kafka template
    template = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    // set the default topic to send to
    template.setDefaultTopic(TOPIC);

    // wait until the partitions are assigned
    for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
      messageListenerContainer.setupMessageListener(new MessageListener<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
          try {
            kafkaEventConsumer.receive(record.value());
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });
      ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer, embeddedKafka.getPartitionsPerTopic());
    }


  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
    embeddedKafka.destroy();
  }


  @Test
  public void testReceive() throws Exception {
    String forecastRequestMessage = "{\"programId\":100011770}";
    ForecastRequest forecastRequest = ForecastRequest.builder().programId(100011770L).build();
    JobDetail jobDetail = JobDetail.builder().jobStatus(JobStatus.complete).build();
    Mockito.when(forecastServiceMock.refreshForecasts(Matchers.any())).thenReturn(jobDetail);
    template.sendDefault(forecastRequestMessage);
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    // validate something
  }

}
```

The problem is, in the above `@Test` method instead of calling the mocked version of `MyService` it is calling the original `MyService` implementation. Also, while debugging my code I found that overridden `onMessage()` is also not getting called. Please help me in finding what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `stop()` all the `MessageListenerContainer`s before  calling their `setupMessageListener()`. Then you will need to `start()` them back to let them to pick up a fresh listener:

```
protected void doStart() {
    ...
    Object messageListener = containerProperties.getMessageListener();
    Assert.state(messageListener != null, "A MessageListener is required");
```

Anyway that sounds like you really would like to mock only your `MyService` which is injected into the real `KafkaEventConsumer`. So, how about to consider to use that like this:

```
@MockBean
private MyServiceImpl myServiceMock;
```

And you won't need to do anything in your `@Before` and no need in the `@InjectMocks`.

The `KafkaEmbedded` can expose its host/port (or brokers) properties to the expected Spring Boot conventional configuration properties like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaEmbedded.getBrokersAsString());
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: how can I stop and start message listner in my code? Can you please provide a sample or reference for the same?

Comment: You have there `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`. Just call its `stop()`! and then after resetting listener `start()`